# How to get ggplot2 to display multiple x labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with values converted into percentages that I would like to plot on the y axis while having their categories on the x axis. this is my dataset for example:

[image]

I can plot it fine in excel with the location and season labelled on the x axis and the experiment and control in paired bars, but How would I do this in R?

Does anyone have any ideas how to add additional labels/groupings on the x axis in ggglot2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to group your data to have "two labels". All you need to do is to plot one variable in the x axis, and color your bars using the second variable of interest.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  season = c(rep("summer", 4), rep("fall", 4), rep("winter", 4)),
  location = c(rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2), rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2), 
               rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2)),
  experiment = c(50, 60, 20, 25, 30, 40, 70, 60, 80, 90, 50, 30),
  control = c(23, 60, 45, 80, 60, 20, 45, 90, 30, 40, 70, 80),
  total = c(35, 60, 25, 40, 50, 30, 60, 70, 40, 50, 80, 50)
)


ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = location,                    # First label goes in x-axis
           y = experiment, 
           fill = season)) +                # Color different seasons differently
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge()) +   # Second label colors bars
  labs(x = "Location", y = "Experiment")
```

If you want more than two labels, you would need to glue column names together and use the new combined label in the x-axis or to fill the bars. For example:

```
# Say you have a time of day variable as well
df$time_of_day = rep(c("morning", "afternoon"), 6)

# Create new column with combined labels
df$combined_labels <- paste(df$location, df$time_of_day, sep = " ")

# Plot using combined labels
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x = combined_labels,
           y = experiment, 
           fill = season)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
             position = position_dodge()) + 
    labs(x = "Location and Time of Day", y = "Experiment")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group_by()` function from the `dplyr` package to group the data by multiple columns. Here's an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example dataset
df <- data.frame(
  season = c(rep("summer", 4), rep("fall", 4), rep("winter", 4)),
  location = c(rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2), rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2), 
               rep("PT", 2), rep("PH", 2)),
  experiment = c(50, 60, 20, 25, 30, 40, 70, 60, 80, 90, 50, 30),
  control = c(23, 60, 45, 80, 60, 20, 45, 90, 30, 40, 70, 80),
  total = c(35, 60, 25, 40, 50, 30, 60, 70, 40, 50, 80, 50)
)

# Group by multiple columns
df_grouped <- df %>% 
  group_by(season, location)

# Plot with multiple groups
ggplot(df_grouped, aes(x = location, y = experiment, fill = season)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  labs(title = "Experiment by Location and Season", x = "Location", y = "Experiment")
```